# How can I mimic the given proof?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-writing, homotopy-theory

The lemma and a part of its proof are given below:

> [image]

Now, I was trying to prove the other part $ g \circ f \simeq g \circ h$.

**My trial:**

Suppose $f,h : X \rightarrow Y$ are homotopic, and $g: Y \rightarrow Z.$

Let $H: X \times I \rightarrow Y$be the homotopy from $f$ to $h$.

Define $F: Y \times I \rightarrow Z$ by:

$$F(y, t) = G(H(x,t),t)$$

Then $F(y,0) = G(H(x,0),0) = G(h_{0}(x),0) = G (f(x),0) = g_{0}(f(x)) = g \circ f$

I am not sure if my last equality correct as I replaced $g_{0}$ by $g$ without having any clue about this, is this step true?

Also, should the function $G$ be known, as I do not know anything other than that $G(x,t) = g_{t}(x)$?

Any help with the proof will be appreciated. Also, any correction for my trial steps is so much welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the function $G$ that you are using? You haven't defined it.

Comment: For that matter, $g_0$ and $h_0$ are not defined either. Most importantly, when you define $F(y,t)$ as $G(H(x,t),t)$ but you realize that you don't even know what $G$ is, alarm bells should go off in your head! That means you have not actually defined $F$ at all, so you cannot continue the proof.

Comment: I think that your main point of confusion is thinking that the homotopy $F$ that you're looking for has to come in the form of a composition of homotopies, maybe from not fully understanding what an homotopy does in each instant $t$. Note that $H(t,x)=h_t(x)$ is just a single variable function when you fix $t$, so the function $g \circ H$ that sends each $(t,x)$ to $(g \circ f_t) (x)$ is perfecly defined.

Comment: does $f_{t}(x)$ is the same as my $h_{t}(x)$@Yagger Mine is $H(x,t) = h_{t}(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is that you want to construct a function $X \times I \to Z$, and you have functions $X \times I \to Y$ and $Y \to Z$. The "obvious" (in retrospect) thing to do is to simply compose the functions, which indeed is correct!

Let $H : X \times I \to Y$ be the homotopy from $f$ to $h$ and let $g : Y \to Z$. Define $F = g \circ H$. $F$ is continuous because it is the composition of two continuous functions, and we see that $$F(x,0) = g(H(x,0)) = g(f(x)) = (g \circ f)(x)$$ while $$F(x,1) = g(H(x,1)) = g(h(x)) = (g \circ h)(x).$$ Thus, $F$ is a homotopy from $g \circ f$ to $g \circ h$.

Comment: @hopefully Since $f$ and $h$ are functions $X \to Y$ and $g$ is a function $Y \to Z$, $g \circ f$ and $g \circ h$ are functions $X \to Z$. A homotopy between two functions $X \to Z$ is a continuous map $X \times I \to Z$.